# Yocto kirkstone RDepends no providers found

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-kirkstone

This is something I came across after Updating my yocto to Kirkstone, this was working fine prior to that.

The error is:
`do_package_qa: QA Issue: /something.sh contained in package testpackage requires /bin/bash, but no providers found in RDEPENDS:testpackage? [file-rdeps]`
which confuses me, as
 `DEPENDS += " bash " RDEPENDS_${PN} += " bash "`
I do have bash in the RDEPENDS

I tried looking for the problem on stack overflow, found some semi related posts, whose solutions sadly did not apply to my problem. I tried installing bash before my testpackage.

Comment: `RDEPENDS_${PN}` is [not valid override syntax](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/migration-guides/migration-3.4.html) in Kirkstone anymore. It has changed to `RDEPENDS:${PN}`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i must have missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RDEPENDS_${PN}` is not a valid override syntax in Kirkstone anymore. It has changed to `RDEPENDS:${PN}`.